# How can I specify kid when signing jwt with SymmetricSecurityKey?

Tags: c#, security, jwt, identity

I am validating jwt tokens at backend where tokens can be issued from several sources with different keys and algorithms.

Earlier I only used to validate using `RsaSha256` keys, and now I'm setting up to accept tokens signed with `HmacSha256`.

The problem is- when validating the token, I used to look at the kid value to resolve the cert/security key. But tokens generated with `HmacSha256` does not include a kid value.

I am currently just checking `kid == null` in the `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` delegate to determine which key should be used to validate (if null use Hmac key, else use matching rsa key). But it works as long as I keep signing with only one Hmac key, if I am required to sign with more than one symmetric keys then I won't be able to determine which one to use to validate.

- How can I include kid with the token?
- If not possible, what is
  recommended way to determine which key to use when validating?
- Also I
  am not 100% certain if accepting mixture of such keys is safe, is it?

Below is roughly my token generator using symmetric key-

```
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{

    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    Issuer = issuer,
    Audience = aud,
    Expires = expirationTime,

    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey),
        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256
        )
};

var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
```

I'm using `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` for both generating and validating tokens.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for the same thing just now.
Just add the KeyId when constructing the SymmetricSecurityKey.

```
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
        new SymmetricSecurityKey(symmetricKey) { KeyId = "Your Key Id" },
        SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256
    )
```